# How to get access to IK bones in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I've created some shapes and connected them with bones, that bones have some names, IKbone1, IKbone2...

so the questions is: How can I access to those bones by name in AS3, because I've tried that in I get an error that there are no object name...

any advice?

Comment: some link or piece of code please

Comment: for example how to access their x and y positions or rotations

Answer (score 1):

[A manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/ik/IKManager.html)

IK structure seems to be rather complex in Flash, you first need to reach the correct armature, then you can get bone by name via `IKArmature.getBoneByName()`. The main data set in those IK bones is stored in points (joints) instead of actual bones.

Comment: why I get 0 armatures on stage using IKManager.numArmatures;, i've added some armature to the stage.. why is that?